# Launch and install applications on EC2 instance using aws sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I don't know If this will be possible at the first place.

The requirement is to launch ec2 instance using aws sdk (I know this is possible) [using](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/ec2-example-creating-an-instance.html) based on some application login.

Then I wanted to install some application on the newly launched instance let's say docker.

Is this possible using sdk? Or My idea itself is wrong and there is a better solution to the scenario?

Can i run a command on a Running instance using SDK?

Comment: We can help you when you can giveus details on what kind of language you are using, aws sdk are available for many languages https://aws.amazon.com/tools/

Comment: i was just looking for if it is possible or not, any language will do, i think if it is possible in one language, i suppose it will be possible in others as well, right?

Comment: Yes, it is 100 percent possible, posted a solution with an example of aws sdk for python ( boto3).
if it helped you, can you accept it as answer so that it may help others in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can install anything on EC2 when it is launched by providing script/commands in userdata section. This is also possible from AWS SDK https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_UserData.html

you can pass command like yum install docker in userdata

UserData='yum install docker'

Comment: I know userData, it actually gives lesser control, because I can't run commands using sdk later on, it's only while starting/restarting.

Answer (score 0):

installing applications uysing cmd on a running command is possible using boto3.

```
ssm_client = boto3.client('ssm')
response = ssm_client.send_command(
            InstanceIds=['i-xxxxxxx'],
            DocumentName="AWS-RunShellScript",
            Parameters={'commands': ['echo "abc" > 1.txt']}, )

command_id = response['Command']['CommandId']
output = ssm_client.get_command_invocation(
      CommandId=command_id,
      InstanceId='i-xxxxxxxx',
    )
print(output)
```

[ssm client](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#SSM.Client.send_command) `Runs commands on one or more managed instances.`

You can also optimize this using function

```
def execute_commands(ssm_client, command, instance_id):
   

    response = client.send_command(
        DocumentName="AWS-RunShellScript", #preconfigured documents
        Parameters={'commands': commands},
        InstanceIds=instance_ids,
    )
    return resp

ssm_client = boto3.client('ssm') 
commands = ['ifconfig']
instance_ids = ['i-xxxxxxxx']
execute_commands_on_linux_instances(ssm_client, commands, instance_ids)
```

Comment: Creating an instance using sdk is possible and is written/reference in the question itself. The question is Can I run a command on a running instance using sdk?

Comment: sorry my bad, updated my answer with docs reference, hope it solves the puporse.